# How to fix the errors about return subtrees from the depth given in parameter

Tags: haskell, tree

I want to return the list of all the subtrees of the initial tree with the depth given in parameter

I've tried to return the list of the tree when the depth is 0 and when depth matching with n, I want to decrement n and apply the map function using my function and the n parameter decremented to the list of subtrees

```hs
data Tree t = Node t [Tree t] deriving (Show, Eq)

exTree :: Tree Int
exTree = Node 1 [ Node 2 [], Node 3 [ Node 4 [], Node 5 [],Node 6 []]]

height :: Tree t -> Int
height (Node _ []) = 1
height (Node _ l) = 1 + maximum (map height l)

treemap :: (t->t) -> Tree t -> Tree t
treemap f (Node x []) = Node (f x) []
treemap f (Node x l) = Node (f x) (map (treemap f) l)

-- Here is the function concerned:

extrForest :: Int -> Tree t -> [Tree t]
extrForest 0 a = [a]
extrForest n (Node _ l) = map (extrForest (n-1)) l
```

Here is the error message:

```hs
Couldn't match type ‘[Tree t]’ with ‘Tree t’
    Expected type: Tree t -> Tree t
      Actual type: Tree t -> [Tree t]
    Relevant bindings include
      l :: [Tree t] (bound at ds2.hs:16:22)
      extrForest :: Int -> Tree t -> [Tree t] (bound at ds2.hs:15:1)
    In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(extrForest (n - 1))’
    In the expression: map (extrForest (n - 1)) l
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want it to do, you should always include sample inputs and outputs. However try to use concatMap instead of map, if it is what you need I'll add it as an answer

Comment: You've understand perfectly, that was that. I've tried concatMap instead of map and it works ! thank you

Comment: `treemap` doesn't need to handle a leaf node specially; `map (treemap f) [] == []`.

Comment: yes, you're right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still don't quite understand what you need, so here is a very ad-hoc solution.

Looking at your error, it is clear that you have the common problem `[a]` vs `[[a]]`.
When you look at the type signature `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` you see that your function has to take an `[a]` and return a simple `[b]`, not `[[b]]`, as this then needs to be mapped over again. However, your `extForest` returns a list of forests, so what you should do, is to concatenate them: `concat . map`. Turns out this is a common thing, and there's a Prelude function to do this: `concatMap :: Foldable t => (a -> [b]) -> t a -> [b]`.

Comment: yes, at one point I tried to add (++) operator before the map function but it didn't work. Now I understand my errors. Thanks again